# iOS 13 public release is not showing in my iPhone Software Update

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been using Beta versions of iOS 13.

Now even after iOS 13 public release is made, My device is still showing iOS 13.1 public beta 4 in the Software update.

What do I need to get the public release ?

Note*
You may wonder why I need the public release, I just want to make sure how it behaves in the public version, since some of my apps is facing few UI issues in iOS 13 beta versions.

Comment: If you already have 13.1 you won‘t get offered the upgrade to 13.0 (which would be a downgrade, actually)

Comment: @nohillside If there is any good procedure for downgrade, please let me know